# Image not showing up when adding the element through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am adding images of cards for a blackjack game and for whatever reason when I try to insert images through JS, they don't appear on the website. The hit button is supposed to add a new random card. The goal is to generate a random suite and a number and add the source accordingly.

```js
let randomSuite;
let randomNum
let count = 1;
var cards = new Array();
const suites = new Array();
suites[0] = "H";
suites[1] = "S";
suites[2] = "C";
suites[3] = "D";
window.onload = function main(){
for(let i = 0 ; i < 56 ; i++){
    randomNum = (Math.random() * 12) + 1;
    cards.push(Math.floor(randomNum));
    console.log(cards[i]);
    count++;
}
}
function hitFunc(){
    randomSuite = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src","PNG-cards-1.3\1C.png");
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    //alert(randomSuite); used to check whether or not my code is running random numbers
    img.id = count;
    count++;
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding : 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#divId {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
}
.main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:black;
}

.img1{
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    margin: 10px auto 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
}

.img2{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 10px auto 20px;
    display: block;
    bottom: 150px;
    width: 7%;
    height: 7%;
}

.hitButton {
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
left: 175px;
bottom: 250px;
}

.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    color: aliceblue;
    object-position: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>first js website</title>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
  h1{text-align: center;}
</style>
<body class="main">
  <div id="divId">
    <h1 class="center">black jack</h1>
    <img src="C:\Users\Adamf\OneDrive\Pictures\Camera Roll\background.jpg" 
    alt="" class="img1">
    <button class="hitButton" id="hitbtn" onclick="hitFunc()">HIT</button>
    <img src="PNG-cards-1.3\1C.png" 
    alt="" class="img2"> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I insert the same photo in html it works fine however when I try to manually add (the same path) it in JavaScript the same image does not want to appear. It will show up as if the image is not found.

edit: I just added the full program to stop confusion. Also, I am very new to JS so forgive my lack of knowledge.

Comment: The `count` isn't declared `let count = 0` and how is this: `PNG-cards-1.3\1C.png` going to change into `PNG-cards-1.3\2C.png`? or `PNG-cards-1.3\KD.png`?

Comment: count is global. I also have an array of H D C S for the different suites. Which i would then add the source as img.src = "PNG-cards-1.3\" + randomNum + suites[randomSuites]+ ".png". Im very new the JS but hopefully that makes sense

Comment: I have also just hard coded the path to show that it wasnt working

Comment: Are these paths local? It's difficult to actually make src to your own computer as a security measure. Are any of the images uploaded to a server?

Comment: Yes they are local

Comment: Im new to js is there a server you could recommend me to use?

Comment: https://imgbb.com/ is free. In fact I think I have the same set of images uploaded to my account.

Comment: Okay thank you. Ill give it a try and let you know. When i link a url using js it seems to work fine for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything wrong with your JS. Just check the image URL. Search on google about img attributes to see if anythings different.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that my function is running since I used an alert to debug it. Also, I need to do it in JS because i need to add a new image every time the button is clicked. I added my entire program just now so you should look to get a better understanding.